# Test void method that has boolean conditions with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to test void method that has boolean conditions inside with Junit

```
/** Method to create request */
public void createRequest(String name) {

  if (verifyName(name)) {
    testRepo.getRequest(name); // Void method from test repo
    demoRepo.testMethod(name); // Another void method from demo repo
  }
}

/** Validate name */
private boolean verifyName(String name) {

 return "Test".equals(name);
}
```

In this case, what is the best approach to test the void method when verifyName() returns `true/false` with JUnit ??

**Expected Test Scenarios:**

1. verifyName() returns `true` --> assert or make sure the methods get executed.
2. verifyName() return `false` --> assert or make sure the methods won't get executed.

Comment: `return "Test".equals(name) ? true : false;`, you can just skip the `? true : false`

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: The goto tools for that are listed [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations). The most relevant tool here is probably [Mockito – Using Spies](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy). You can spy on `testRepo` and `demoRepo` and check if they get called. Here is a question very similar to yours: [How to verify if method was called from other with same class by mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755449/how-to-verify-if-method-was-called-from-other-with-same-class-by-mockito)

Answer (score 0):

you can verify if some function is called or not based on the condition

try something like that

```
@Test
public void testValidName() {
    service.createRequest("Test");
    verify(testRepo, times(1)).getRequest();
    verify(demoRepo, times(1)). testMethod();
}
```

Comment: They did not mention mocks/spies in their question and you did not mention it in your answer. If you are going to suggest a certain pattern or framework, you should call it out and explain how/why it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write two scenarios :

```
@Captor
private String ArgumentCaptor<String> nameCaptor;

@Test
public void testForValidName() {
    service.createRequest("Test");
    Mockito.verify(testRepo, Mockito.times(1)).getRequest(nameCaptor.capture());
    Mockito.verify(demoRepo, Mockito.times(1)).testMethod(nameCaptor.capture());
    List<String> capturedValues = nameCaptor.getValues();
    Assert.assertEquals("Test", capturedValues.get(0));
    Assert.assertEquals("Test", capturedValues.get(1));
}

@Test
public void testForInValidName() {
   service.createRequest("Test1");
   Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(testRepo);
   Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(demoRepo);
}
```